# What event fires when a WebKit WebApp is "terminated"

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am in the process of developing a Web App for iOS and am using the DOMApplicationCache. I know that Web Apps can not run in the background, but I still would like to simulate a resume of the app when the user switches to another app and returns to the web app later.

In order to do this I at least need to record when the Web App terminates/unloads. But the window.unload does not seem to fire.

Does anybody have an idea how to catch the termination of a WebApp running?

PS: on a related question, where does the console.log go when apple-mobile-web-app-capable is yes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the "pageshow" event to detect when the app has resumed. This event will fire when user returns to your app from a different safari tab. It will also fire when user clicks the home button and then comes back to the app by clicking on safari button

```
     <script>
    window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(){
        alert("page shown");
    }, false);
  </script>
```

I have tested this on the iOS simulator and its working as I described above.

Answer (score 3):

I have an answer. It's not what we were hoping for.

The technical definition of unload from http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html is:

> The unload event occurs when the DOM
>   implementation removes a document from
>   a window or frame. This event is valid
>   for BODY and FRAMESET elements.

I also got a reply from some in the know at Apple: "Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find an event that fires when the Home button is clicked!  I think the most appropriate event for this might be the pagehide event.  This event actually does fire in Safari on iOS when you switch to the "tabs" view to open a new page, but not when you click the home screen icon :-("

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. So the only way to determine if a webapp has been "resumed" is to compare a heartbeat stored locally?

Comment: just in case anyone doesn't understand, this is the "heartbeat" Jamgold is referring to. I only comment to help others in their quest ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940657/handling-standby-on-ipad-using-javascript/4941098#4941098

Comment: Awesome! The `pagehide` event is queued even when the `home` and `lock` buttons are pressed in 4.3.4, but it isn't until you reopen Safari (or unlock the device) that it gets executed. I don't think it gets any better than this. It's good enough for me.