# Detect moving to a new tab in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I have a series of pages that open popups (new tabs in Mobile Safari.) Each of these popups needs to know when they are the focused or not. On desktops, we use `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` to drive this behavior. However, none of these events work on iPad. I also tried `window.onpageshow` and `window.onpagehide` which don't seem to fire at the right times either. I have a test HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
console.log('Hello');
window.onblur = function(e) { console.log('blur'); };
window.onfocus = function(e) { console.log('focus'); };
window.onpagehide = function(e) { console.log('pagehide'); };
window.onpageshow = function(e) { console.log('pageshow'); };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In theory, when you click 'Click Me', you should get a blur event when the new window appears. But this doesn't happen on Mobile Safari. `onpagehide` and `onpageshow` show no love either, they only help for detecting when you're about to close the tab.

How can I get the behavior I'm looking for in Mobile Safari? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 6):

Try this: https://gist.github.com/1122546

It's a Visibilty API polyfill. Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like just the ticket!

Comment: actually according to Chris Keele's comment, that may not work in Mobile Safari. I don't have my iPad on me right now - if what he says is true, is there a way around it for Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that `onblur` can be detected, but this is a code to detect `onfocus`:

```
var timestamp=new Date().getTime();
function checkResume()
{
    var current=new Date().getTime();
    if(current-timestamp>5000)
    {
        var event=document.createEvent("Events");
        event.initEvent("focus",true,true);
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    timestamp=current;
}
window.setInterval(checkResume,50);
```

Then you just write:

```
document.addEventListener("focus",function()
{
    alert("Focus detected");
},false);
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5 pause JS in none active tab.
Maybe this topic could help you.

[ios 5 pauses javascript when tab is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977170/ios-5-pauses-javascript-when-tab-is-not-active)

[Handling standby on iPad using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940657/handling-standby-on-ipad-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked the same thing a little more recently so I'll just link this answer to my older one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817295/javascript-pauses-on-ipad-when-changing-tab-is-there-a-way-to-know-when-coming/14656831#14656831).

Mageek's method is very similar to what I'm doing, but will also fire on a scroll event or when the keyboard is visible.  Preventing the behavior upon scrolling wasn't terribly challenging, but I never got around to looking up on-screen keyboard events.

My object also leverages requestAnimationFrame and will use the focus hack only as a fallback, opting to use the Visibility API where available (ideally making it future-proof).

Comment: this will only tell when you come back into the tab, right? I would like to know when the tab that has this code is no longer onscreen, and know it before the tab has been reopened.