# Pause a sound when user leaves the page on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile-safari

I am playing audio in Background of an application but I want to stop when user minimises or Safari goes to background.

I have already tried `working element.onfocus`.

I also tried to use `window.requestAnimFrame` but its results are not satisfactory.

I can't figure out how to stop the audio.

Comment: Look my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085409/detect-moving-to-a-new-tab-in-mobile-safari/11164387#11164387. It's to detect the focus!

Comment: @Mageek I have to stop the audio when the application tab is hidden or minimised....please suggest something.??

Comment: "When the application tab is hidden or minimised" means onblur, and I don't know any way how to detect the "onblur" event :( If you find a way later, it would be good to post it here.

Comment: @Mageek it is possible, check answer.

Answer (score 1):

you might have success with the `pageshow` and `pagehide` events, which are triggered when safari goes to the background.

however there is no event that i know of, when you switch tabs within safari.

also here is a small library that does most of the work for you: https://github.com/zynga/jukebox

Answer (score 0):

I found the most success with the `visibilitychange` event. For whatever reason `pagehide` wasn't triggering for me on mobile. They both have ~97% browser support.

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    backgroundMusic.play();
  } else {
    backgroundMusic.pause();
  }
});
```

MDN itself recommends `visibilitychange` as that "The best event to use to signal the end of a user's session". (quote from the `pagehide` MDN page)

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Browser support: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_document_visibilitychange_event

Answer (score -1):

As answer to you and to Mageek comment, you should check the onfocus event and the onblur event (it is possible) prefered using jQuery :

```
$(window).focus(function() { 
//enable sound
}); 

$(window).blur(function() { 
//disable sound
});
```

This will probably do the trick, but havn't tested it.

Comment: blur and focus events are not defined in mobile safari. As I have given in the post I have already tried working out with them....if it did helped.

Comment: I havn't found any information about your claim. are you sure about that?

Comment: yaa......i m sure that it is not working as i have tried implementing it before i post this question here.