# Phones get lock during running javascript webapp

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

I developed a web application using javascript on my website, I expect all devices can run my application, everything is right but in smartphones like iPhone, the device locks during running the application, I want the app to be something like video that devices know it should not get lock, what is your suggestion? I was thinking to use flash but as you know iPhone does not support flash.
thanks for your help

Comment: Please show what you have, and expand on your question. At present there's not much for people to help you with!

Comment: Does it work in desktop safari? How those your code look like? do you know where it hangs? ...? Please provide some more details. THX

Comment: @LeeTaylor well it is so simple, the device looks at my application as a HTML page so after some times the screens turn off, how to avoid that?

Comment: @winner_joiner it does not hang, the apps work fine, the only problem is that iPhone locks after some minute, that's it

Comment: Okay i got it you are looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642026/prevent-idle-state-when-uploading-web-app-on-ios , it refers to uploads but should also solve your problem

Comment: @winner_joiner tnx, exactly what i was looking for