# Detect closing browser tab via JavaScript in the Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari

I need to obtain any event when user clicks the close button of the current browser tab. No one method which I use in such cases worked (for example onunload, unload and pagehide events handling not detection close tab, only change or update tab).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5):

> unload Deprecated, use pagehide instead.

It looks like pagehide actually fires when you click on the "tabs" view to open a new page (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401764/what-event-fires-when-a-webkit-webapp-is-terminated) in ghenne's answer) but other than that, no event even exists for closing browser on Mobile Safari! Found info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554479/js-event-to-see-if-mobile-safari-has-been-closed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940657/handling-standby-on-ipad-using-javascript/4941098#4941098) as well.